# Does Mysql search performance depend on the disk space?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We are using mysql 5.7 version.

We have two tables t1 and t2, t1 stores the audit information of t2.
At a database level t1 and t2 are not related by any foreign key relationship.

t1 has around ~30 million records and t2 has ~3 million records.

What we observed was, The queries which used to take longer time initially started showing good improvement once t1 data is truncated.

```
But I couldn't find any logical explanation on the reason, Did anyone observe this and what could be the reason behind this?
```

Comment: What is the query and what is the server load? Are there writes?

Comment: We did this experiment on a copy of our actual server, so literally, the load was zero and no other operations as well.

Comment: And how was the load before it was copied? SQL never forgets. And what is the query and data structure? I'm absolutely not surprised by your experience.

Comment: The impact of size is dependent on many factors. Is the entire dataset resident in memory? If not, what type of disks are the datafiles stored on? What is the total size of the database (sum of all data and indices)? What is the size of the buffer pool? What is the structure of these two tables (CREATE TABLE statements)? Provide examples of the queries (and EXPLAIN output) that you noticed the performance difference for.

Comment: Show us `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`